# Empty spaces added around HTML text when using Angular interpolation

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Any idea why an empty space is added before text in HTML when using interpolation in Angular?

Exemple in my Angular *HTML template*:

```html
<div class="info-title">
   {{ "Beds" }}
</div>
```

Result after *ng serve*:

```
<div _ngcontent-bej-c49="" class="info-title"> Beds </div>
```

You can see that some spaces are added before and after *Beds*.

Do you have any idea of what I could do to prevent those spaces from appearing?

*This is an exemple and I'm aware that there's no need to use an interpolation here.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the whitespace before and after the JavaScript.

```
<div class="info-title">{{ property.bedAmount > 1 ? "Beds" : "Bed" }}</div>
```